# Internal rate limiting in Node.js for AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function in AWS that is calling an API that has a rate limit of 120 calls per second. It's a paginated listing API, so it'll loop and keep hitting this API until there's no more pages left to get. How do I limit the calls so that my lambda will only hit this API 120 times a second?

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe your lambda have 10 of concurrency, i mean, though you have a rate limit of 120 call per second you lambda in the same time(concurrency) run a 10 lambdas with this configuration, check the concurrency configuration in your lambda for change to 1, if still this issue i will recommend you to use the SQS, because with a queue you can have better control of how to send information for example an API.

Comment: There's only one lambda running at the same time. Currently, there is a loop which makes the API calls. Using SQS would solve the rate limiting, but also making the process run too slow. The API call can get 60 records at a time, and with a maximum of 500,000 records, at maximum calls, that's still more than an hour of processing. I was looking for whether I can simply limit the rate API calls themselves in the lambda code.